# Navigation between folders, similar to Google Drive

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, routes

I want to do a navigation between folders type Google Drive in Angular 2. For the moment I have been part of the components, and still I do not touch the backend.

```
Create folders
Home:
- FolderA,
    -CarpetaC
    -FileC
    -CarpetaF
- B,
- FileX,
- ArchiveY,
```

I want to work it as it does on Google Drive:

[image: Screenshot of Google Drive]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5BG625ApbuQUWp2dU1aOG1aU00

I have defined my model element which are folders or directories.

```
Interface Element {
_id: string,
Name: string,
Shared ?: Array <number>,
Father: string,
Child: string,
Type: string,
Icon: string
...
...
}
```

I've only made the components, and I get access from the parent to the children, but what I lack this component.

```
Home-FolderA-FolderC
```

Suppose someone joins the link directly

I should show this navigation structure as it does drive.

That folder suppose that it is

```
Home-FolderA-FolderC
  -ChildC1,
  -ChildC2,
  -ChildC3
```

However it is the id of the element 0B5BG625ApbuQUWp2dU1aOG1aU00, as I would to return the structure I want, I will use MongoDB as a database.

I want to do something like find the id to which it refers and then do a search up, serious with a true populate? Then I would have so reference. However, I feel that I am not taking several considerations, someone has done something similar? Angular 2 or any language to analyze it.

PS: Sorry for not sending you pictures, but it's for work.

Comment: An `Element` doesn't need to keep a reference to its parent(s) and its child(ren), it only adds complexity to your model. Just keep a `parent` property on each element (or `parents` if an element may have multiple parents). Then, given the id of a specific folder, you should be able to recreate its exact position in the tree (i.e. find all its ancestors up to the root node and find all its descendants). Post if you have more questions.